# Download Complete event handler is not being called

Tags: c#, webclient

I have this C# code that does not do the job. This code should run a code when the download is complete. But it does not work.

Code:

```
private void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("web/data/main/web.zip", "web/");
}

private void flatToggle2_CheckedChanged(object sender)
{
    if (flatToggle2.Checked)
    {
        //Create File
        Directory.CreateDirectory("web/data/main/");
        timer2.Start();
        bunifuProgressBar1.Show();
        bunifuCustomLabel1.Show();

        //Downloand
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
            client.DownloadFile("https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC15/binaries/httpd-2.4.29-Win64-VC15.zip", "web/data/main/web.zip");
        }
    }
    else
    {               
    }
}
```

This is the code that does not work

```
private void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("web/data/main/web.zip", "web/");
}
```

I tried to run this code without the Unzip but it did not work so I need help with this code.

Comment: Define "did not work". What happened? Errors?

Comment: no errors just it does not run this code when done:

Comment: private void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("web/data/main/web.zip", "web/");

}

Comment: Does it throw an exception? What happens if you try to unzip the file from the command line/File Manager? Or is it simply that the function is not called?

Comment: i am kind of new here so

Comment: it does not run the private void thing

Comment: I think I am correct in saying that `DownloadFile()` does not use a completed callback since it is synchronous, so just directly call `ExtractToDirectory()` on the line after the `DownloadFile()`.

Comment: so can you send me the whole code because i am kinda new at C# sooo.

Comment: The other issue is that `DownloadStringCompleted` is used but you're calling `DownloadFile`. Using the `DownloadFileCompleted` event might be important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, [`DownloadFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) is synchronous, so there is no callback needed. Try instead just:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCompleted);
    client.DownloadFile("https://www.apachelounge.com/download/VC15/binaries/httpd-2.4.29-Win64-VC15.zip", "web/data/main/web.zip");
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("web/data/main/web.zip", "web/");
}
```

This should suffice.